# lift-json XPath \\ operator has different return type depending on num matches

Tags: scala, xpath, lift, lift-json, json4s

I would expect `json \\ "something"` to always return the same type of object (or at least something that's always isomorphic) *for the same query on data with the same schema*, however, consider:

```scala
val json1 = ("people" -> List(
  ("person" -> ("name" -> "Joe")),
  ("person" -> ("name" -> "Marilyn"))))

val json2 = ("people" -> List(
  ("person" -> ("name" -> "Joe"))))

val json3 = ("people" -> List[(String, String)]())

println((json1 \\ "name")) // JObject(List(JField(name,JString(Joe)), JField(name,JString(Marilyn))))
println((json2 \\ "name")) // JString(Joe)
println((json3 \\ "name")) // JObject(List())

// which causes the following construction to sometimes fail
println((json1 \\ "name").children map { case JField(_, JString(name)) => name })
// List(Joe, Marilyn)
println((json2 \\ "name").children map { case JField(_, JString(name)) => name })
// List()  !!!!!
println((json3 \\ "name").children map { case JField(_, JString(name)) => name })
// List()
```

...so the n = 0 and n >= 2 cases are handled consistently, but n = 1 special cases to `JValue`.

Why is this happening? Is it by design?

**Compare with mapping over a `List`**

```scala
val people = List(Person(name = "Joe"), Person(name = "Mary"))
people.map(_.name) # => returns a List

val people = List(Person(name = "Joe"))
people.map(_.name) # => returns a List

val people = List()
people.map(_.name) # => returns a List
```

**Compare with Scala's XML**

```scala
val xml1 = <people> <person><name>Joe</name></person> <person><name>Marylin</name></person> <person><name>Erik</name></person> </people>
val xml2 = <people> <person><name>Erik</name></person> </people>
val xml3 = <people> </people>

Seq(xml1, xml2, xml3).map(_ \\ "name") foreach (x => println(s"${x.getClass}\t${x.length}\t$x"))

// OUTPUT:    
// class scala.xml.NodeSeq$$anon$1  3   <name>Joe</name><name>Marylin</name><name>Erik</name>
// class scala.xml.NodeSeq$$anon$1  1   <name>Erik</name>
// class scala.xml.NodeSeq$$anon$1  0
```

so why shouldn't one expect the lift-json `\\` operator to have the same semantics?

**The doc** at http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/#net.liftweb.json.package has:

> XPath-like expression to query **JSON fields** by name. Returns all matching fields.

Comment: discussion at: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/sf9ch59wEnI/XlPRq5juo8MJ

Answer (score 1):

In Json4s `\\` now always returns a `JArray`, see [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/commit/af01271a37a9bc71fc2e1881547067959073451c).

```
val json1 =
  parse("""
    |{
    |  "people": [{
    |    "name": "Joe"
    |  }, {
    |    "name": "Marilyn"
    |  }]
    |}
  """.stripMargin)

val json2 =
  parse("""
    |{
    |  "people": [{
    |    "name": "Joe"
    |  }]
    |}
  """.stripMargin)


println(json1 \\ "name")
// JArray(List(JString(Joe), JString(Marilyn)))

println(json2 \\ "name")
// JArray(List(JString(Joe)))
```

Comment: That's nice—I think they might be fixing it in Lift 3.x too :)

Comment: In the latest version 3.5.0 I get JString(Joe) and  JObject(List((name,JString(Joe)), (name,JString(Marilyn))))